# Show 0 Not Null With Pivot

Tags: sql-server-2008, coalesce

Why is my `Coalesce()` statement in my initial `Select` statement not replacing the `Null` with a 0?

```
Select * From
(
    Select a.orderstatus As [Stat], Coalesce(Count(b.id), '0') As [Count], b.region
    From orderstatus a
    Left Join saleinfo b
    on b.orderstatus = a.orderstatus
    Group By a.orderstatus, b.region
) one
    pivot ( Max([Count]) For region In ([East], [West], [North], [South]) ) pv
```

Comment: Because you are using the `COALESCE` in the wrong place. It should be in the outer `SELECT`

Comment: count() can not return null. It either return zero or non-zero value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using it in the inner query, whereas the problem is that the record doesn't it exist so the PIVOT is creating the NULL after the inner query has been processed. If your query (`one`) returned:

```
Stat    Count   Region
-------------------------
Stat1   0       East
Stat2   2       East
Stat1   5       West
```

You will end up with a Pivot Table like

```
Stat    East    West    North   South
---------------------------------------
Stat1   0       5       NULL    NULL
Stat2   2       NULL    NULL    NULL
```

For example you get `NULL` for `(Stat2, West)` because there is no result in your subquery, so the `COALESCE` does not help. Your work around would be to just use `COUNT` in the `PIVOT` itself:

```
SELECT  pvt.OrderStatus, pvt.East, pvt.West, pvt.North, pvt.South
FROM    (   SELECT  os.OrderStatus, si.Region, si.ID
            FROM    OrderStatus AS os
                    LEFT JOIN SaleInfo AS si
                        ON si.OrderStatus = b.OrderStatus
        ) AS t
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(ID)
            FOR Region IN ([East], [West], [North], [South])
        ) AS pvt;
```

Or to put the `COALESCE` in the outer select:

```
SELECT  pvt.OrderStatus, 
        East = COALESCE(pvt.East, 0), 
        West = COALESCE(pvt.West, 0), 
        North = COALESCE(pvt.North, 0), 
        South = COALESCE(pvt.South, 0)
FROM    (   SELECT  os.OrderStatus, si.Region, [Count] = COUNT(si.ID)
            FROM    OrderStatus AS os
                    LEFT JOIN SaleInfo AS si
                        ON si.OrderStatus = b.OrderStatus
        ) AS t
        PIVOT
        (   MAX([Count])
            FOR Region IN ([East], [West], [North], [South])
        ) AS pvt;
```

I much prefer the first option though.

---

**EDIT**

Example showing 0 returned for non existent data when using `COUNT`:

```
SELECT  pvt.Stat, pvt.East, pvt.West, pvt.North, pvt.South
FROM    (VALUES
            ('Stat1', 'East', 1),
            ('Stat2', 'East', 2),
            ('Stat1', 'West', 3)
        ) t (Stat, Region, ID)
        PIVOT
        (   COUNT(ID)
            FOR Region IN ([East], [West], [North], [South])
        ) AS pvt;
```

Comment: There could still be `NULL`s there though. The solution is to use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`  in your `SELECT`: `SELECT  pvt.OrderStatus, ISNULL(pvt.East,0) East....`

Comment: @Lamak in what scenario does `COUNT` return `NULL`?

Comment: Is not the `COUNT` that returns null is that there can be a row for a particular stat that just doesn't have a value for East, West, North or South

Comment: @Lamak because the aggregate used is `COUNT` it will return 0, not null. I have added a simple, reproducible example to the answer to show, that even though no row exists for a region of `North` for `stat1` in the sample data, the output will still be 0, because that is how `COUNT` works.